# Prove by contradiction integer ends with 325

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> Prove that a positive integer that ends in 325 can’t be the square of
> an integer.

I'm not sure how to even approach this, I know that $325 = 5^2 \cdot 13$ but that hasn't led me anywhere.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your attempts to your question.

Answer (score 2):

A square must leave remainder $0, 1, $ or $4$ when divided by $8$.

What is the remainder when an integer ending in $325$ is divided by $8$?